# "Я подошел к Вам и руку подал и предложил дружить". Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

Должна ли быть запятая перед каким-либо союзом **И**?

Comment: Людмила, к сведению: если Вы считаете мою правку некорректной, то можете ее "откатить" (т. е вернуть к прежней версии).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Я подошел к Вам, и руку подал, и предложил дружить*. Однородные члены, союз повторяющийся, действий три, по парам в данном виде разделить трудно, значит, две запятых.